# How did ffmpeg appear on my Windows computer?

Tags: windows, ffmpeg

`ffmpeg` is a great program to (among other things) create videos from lots of images and vice versa. I just recently learned about it and used it on my Linux machine to create time-lapse videos. The thing is...

Yesterday I was very tired and I needed to export some images from video. I just absent-mindedly entered `ffmpeg` in the windows command prompt and this is what I got:

[image: image description]

But I don't remember that I have ever:

- installed ffmpeg
- AND added it to system `%PATH%`

Which software does include ffmpeg with its instalation?

Comment: Use the `where` command to find out where it is. Works much like `which` on Bash and whatnot.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks, it was installed with ImageMagick C++ library. I didn't know about that command.

Comment: check the date ffmpeg files were written then do dir /s/b on all files and see what other files were written on that date then you might find the "author" program

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some games as well as movie editing softwares installs and uses ffmpeg and automatically adds it to `%PATH%`.

I've had it be installed with virtualdub and even with some smaller indie games.